# How to render composition

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I have rendered an image and am doing composition on it. Is it possible to apply the composition to the already render image without rerendering it completely? It would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Render Layers and the *Composite* node. Then use the *Image* node under *Add > Input > Image* and import the image of your render. Then do your compositing, and use the *File Output* node under *Add > Output > File Output*.

To output the file, use the Render Image button again. It should not re-render your scene.

Here is an example:
[image: delete these nodes]
[image: use input image and file output nodes instead]